# NSButton gets an unexpected colour tone when the app starts

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

This is how the button should look like. It simply an ImageButton (NSButton) with a picture.  The picture looks blue in IB.

[image]

This is how I have designed it in IB:
[image]

It has an `Image` called `mac_PremiumButton` and a Tint of `White`.

After starting the app the colour gets really strange. I can't find the reason behind it. I don't get this in iOS but only macOS.

[image]

I have created a minimal reproducible demo on my GitHub to show the problem:
https://github.com/houmie/CocoaPlayground

**Build and start the app, then click on the menu symbol as shown below.**

[image]

Comment: Why is someone downvoting this? I even provided the https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that Stackoverflow recommends.

Comment: See Complete: Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included **in the question itself**

Comment: @Willeke Thanks. I have edited the question. And provided more information. Let me know if you are happy with it.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the issue in a small simple test project?

Comment: @Willeke Sorry in that project I have added you will see this example as well. I have entered three issues I'm facing in the same project. The button has a different colour before the app has started and a different shade after the app has started. Let me know if you can't spot the button in my sample project. Thanks